# translation does not work with text_domain

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation, textdomain

I am trying to translate my custom plugin.

I can translate my plugin if I place the `fr_CA.po/.mo` into my
`wp-content\languages\plugins` manually.

But I would like to be able to put my .po/.mo into my plugins folder in `"myplugin/languages"`

Well, in the main file, I have this:

```
 * Text Domain: myplugin
 * Domain Path: /languages/
```

my text

```
    add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_load_textdomain' );

function myplugin_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
```

all my `.po / .mo` is in that folder `myplugin/languages/`

My Wordpress is in `fr_CA` ( WordPress 4.7.2–fr_CA)

I have a `fr_FR.po /fr_CA.po` (and their `.mo`).

---

Like I said previously, my plugin change the language if I put my `.po/.mo` into the `wp-content\languages\plugins` and I change the `fr_FR(.mo/.po)` to `myplugin-fr_FR(.mo/.po)`

but I would like to keep my `.po/.mo` into my plugins folder.

Anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code of [`load_plugin_textdomain`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/) it becomes appararent that the function will first look for `$domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo'` (so, that's `myplugin-fr_FR.mo`) in `WP_LANG_DIR . '/plugins/' . $mofile`.

Only when the file is not there, it will start looking at the specified path and if it is not there in the main plugin directory. So, if you don't get the mo-file in the specified directory, either it isn't there or you are supplying the wrong path.

I cannot see whether you have made any typos, but instead of combining `dirname` and `plugin_basename` you might want to stick to [`plugin_dir_path`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) to supply the correct directory.